# local database null result

Tags: database, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am trying to create a local database. I made some inserts, but when I run the code I get the "result = null" error:

```
var selectStmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
selectStmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, dbErrorHandler);
selectStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
selectStmt.text = "SELECT * FROM table1";
selectStmt.execute();

var result:SQLResult = selectStmt.getResult();
var numResults:int = result.data.length;
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLStatement is asynchronous, you could do "getResult()" only in a "flash.events.SQLEvent.RESULT" event listener